# Jquery/Javascript Animation

Tags: javascript, dom-events, jquery-animate

How would I go about making divs appear and disappear in sequential order?  My plan is to have a 6 different divs: 1-6 appear in sequential order.  Then after a couple of seconds, they will disappear (6-1) and reappear in sequential order again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that should do the trick:

```
for(var i=0;i<6;i++)
  $('#div'+i).delay(i*500).fadeIn().delay(4000-i*500).fadeOut();
```

.delay() was introduced in jQuery 1.4.